# Cypress OOM error when running in a Gitlab pipeline job

Tags: docker, gitlab, cypress, pipeline, cicd

When I attempt run Cypress inside of a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline job, I always get an error at the start of my tests that says, "Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid..."

For the base image of the job, I'm using the latest image for cypress/included.

I'm executing cypress inside of my script with "npx cypress run"

I made sure that the image was returning a root user.